# MVC: How to know which input value from HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Let me try to explain my situation as simple as possible first:

Suppose I have a page which contains multiple [input type='File']. Some of them may be selected a file and some are not.

In my httppost method, I know I need to use parameter like "IEnumerable files"  to get filenames, and also each [input] name I should define either = 'files' or 'files[0]','files[1]', etc.....

My question is: when getting a list of HttpPostedFileBase, how could I determine which file belongs to which input control？ As some inputs may leave blank.

Also because these [input] are created dynamically and there is no fixed number of it, I could not hard-code the parameter in httppost method for each of them.

Comment: If they are dynamic why you want to know which one belongs to what?

Comment: If the user don't select a file also you can see the no. of items in the collection equal to the no. of file upload controls, so you could use index approach.

Comment: Mark, my form has a list of objects as Model. This <input file> is just 1 property. So some objects may have this property blank (no file selected by user). From testCoder's "Request.Files.AllKeys[]" solution, I could set names of these inputs to be ie "file_ObjectId". Then I could compare to know which object hasn't been selected a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file1" />
    <input type="file" name="file2"/>
    <input type="file" name="file3"/>
    <input type="file" name="file4"/>
    <input type="file" name="file5"/>

    <input type="submit" value="go" />
}
```

Controller:

```
  var uploaded = Request.Files.AllKeys
      .Select(x => new {file = Request.Files[x], name = x})
            .Where(x => x.file.ContentLength > 0).ToList();
```

The "uploaded" anonymouse type will contains file belonging to input control name, and will conatins only input names which selected

Comment: Hi testCoder, your solution looks great! So actually the "input name" can be defined as any string. Is it correct? ie the unique seq of a record, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {
    foreach (var file in files) {
             if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
               var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
               var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
               file.SaveAs(path);
             }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Here for every file you can check whether file is exist or not.

Comment: Hi Ruchir, I have tried this solution before. Actually if I have 3 input but only 1st & 3rd inputs have value, the files[] I got gives me 2 items, but I could not now which belong to which. Instead, I need to create another Model with "IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files" as property, then change parameter of Index() action to be that Model, then I could tell 2nd input doesn't have input

Comment: Hi Samuel, Above mention code is for when you've dynamic file upload controls and the name of your all controls are same. Let's say if you've a file upload control with "Add More" link at that time if you add 3 controls then files[] will give you 3 items but if you've selected only two files then also it'll it will give you 3 items in that two has files and one has null value.

Comment: But if you've 3 fixed file upload controls then you can easily access them by giving diffident names and then you can access them as you access all other controls with property type HttpPostedFileBase.

Answer (score 0):

If you've fixed numbers of file upload controls then you can define your model like

```
    public class FileUpload
        {
            public HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload1 { get; set; }
            public HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload2 { get; set; }
            public HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload3 { get; set; }
        }
```

and then from action you can access them like below

```
     public ActionResult Index(Mvc4Application.Models.FileUpload objFileUpload)
    {
          // Do some code like here you can check for each 3 files like
          if(objFileUpload.FileUpload1 != null)
          {
             // Some code
          }
        return View();
    }
```

For more you can click [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx)