# How to match checkbox ids with files in IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>

Tags: c#, html, httppostedfilebase

I created a model at which user can select checkboxes of states and upload a file for selected states. Since, for each state, there is a upload button created with the (input type="file") property, Html.BeginForm sends all HttpPostedFileBase objects even though they are not created by the user.
The problem is, I cannot match the states and uploaded files. 
Is there a way that I can get them matched at server side or at the front end?

[image]

[image]

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResaleCertificateUpload", "CustomerLookup", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="row" id="usStates">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.US_States.Length; i++)
        {

            if (0 == i % 3)
            {
                <div id="taxCertificateRow" + @i.ToString() class="row"></div>
            }

            int index = i / 3 + (i % 3) * ((@Model.US_States.Length + 1) / 3); //Order states 
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <label>
                    @{ 
                        string stateCheckboxId = "state+" + Model.US_States[index].Abbreviations;
                    }
                    <!--do the same for CA-->
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxState" id='@stateCheckboxId' name="states" value="@Model.US_States[index].Name" onclick="stateCheckboxClicked('@stateCheckboxId', 'file+@Model.US_States[index].Abbreviations')">
                    <span>@Model.US_States[index].ToString() &nbsp;</span>
                </label>
                <input type="file" name="passedInFiles" id="file+@Model.US_States[index].Abbreviations" style="display:none" />
            </div>
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer - It does exactly what you want :) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13157799/2865073)